# ffmpeg command execution never stops

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to concatenate 3 videos of different resolutions and overlaying 2 videos as transition effects(though the chroma key color removal is not yet implemented) between videos using below command:

```
ffmpeg 
-i input1.mp4 
-i input2.mp4 
-i input3.mp4 
-i transition1.mp4 
-i transition2.mp4 
-filter_complex 
"[0:v]pad=width=1080:height=1920:x=(1080-iw)*0.5:y=(1920-ih)*0.5:color=black[video0];
[1:v]pad=width=1080:height=1920:x=(1080-iw)*0.5:y=(1920-ih)*0.5:color=black[video1];
[2:v]pad=width=1080:height=1920:x=(1080-iw)*0.5:y=(1920-ih)*0.5:color=black[video2];
[video0][video1][video2]concat=n=3:v=1:a=0[outv];
[3:v]scale=w=1080:h=1920[t0];
[4:v]scale=w=1080:h=1920[t1];
[outv][t0]overlay=enable='between(t,6.6045,9.6335)'[out0];
[out0][t1]overlay=enable='between(t,12.5655,15.6165)'[out1];
[0:a][1:a][2:a]concat=n=3:v=0:a=1[audio]" 
-c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -map [out1] -map [audio] -preset ultrafast output.mp4
```

I get success only with few videos. Most of the times the command execution never stops. It keeps on appending something to the output video file even for hours. Here is the output from console:

```
ffmpeg version v4.4-dev-416
     Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
      built with Android (6454773 based on r365631c2) clang version 9.0.8 (https://android.googlesource.com/toolchain/llvm-project 98c855489587874b2a325e7a516b99d838599c6f) (based on LLVM 9.0.8svn)
      configuration: --cross-prefix=aarch64-linux-android- --sysroot=/files/android-sdk/ndk/21.3.6528147/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot --prefix=/home/taner/Projects/mobile-ffmpeg/prebuilt/android-arm64/ffmpeg --pkg-config=/usr/bin/pkg-config --enable-version3 --arch=aarch64 --cpu=armv8-a --cc=aarch64-linux-android24-clang --cxx=aarch64-linux-android24-clang++ --extra-libs='-L/home/taner/Projects/mobile-ffmpeg/prebuilt/android-arm64/cpu-features/lib -lndk_compat' --target-os=android --enable-neon --enable-asm --enable-inline-asm --enable-cross-compile --enable-pic --enable-jni --enable-optimizations --enable-swscale --enable-shared --enable-v4l2-m2m --disable-outdev=fbdev --disable-indev=fbdev --enable-small --disable-openssl --disable-xmm-clobber-test --disable-debug --enable-lto --disable-neon-clobber-test --disable-programs --disable-postproc --disable-doc --disable-htmlpages --disable-manpages --disable-podpages --disable-txtpages --disable-static --disable-sndio --disable-schannel --disable-securetransport --disable-xlib --disable-cuda --disable-cuvid --disable-nvenc --disable-vaapi --disable-vdpau --disable-videotoolbox --disable-audiotoolbox --disable-appkit --disable-alsa --disable-cuda --disable-cuvid --disable-nvenc --disable-vaapi --disable-vdpau --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-gmp --enable-gnutls --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libass --enable-iconv --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libxml2 --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libshine --enable-libspeex --enable-libwavpack --enable-libkvazaar --enable-libx264 --enable-gpl --enable-libxvid --enable-gpl --enable-libx265 --enable-gpl --enable-libvidstab --enable-gpl --enable-libilbc --enable-libopus --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libaom --enable-libtwolame --disable-sdl2 --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-zlib --enable-mediacodec
      libavutil      56. 55.100 / 56. 55.100
      libavcodec     58. 96.100 / 58. 96.100
      libavformat    58. 48.100 / 58. 48.100
      libavdevice    58. 11.101 / 58. 11.101
      libavfilter     7. 87.100 /  7. 87.100
      libswscale      5.  8.100 /  5.  8.100
      libswresample   3.  8.100 /  3.  8.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'input1.mp4':
      Metadata:
        major_brand     : 
    mp42
        minor_version   : 
    0
        compatible_brands: 
isommp42
        creation_time   : 
    2020-08-12T17:21:49.000000Z
        com.android.version: 
    9
      Duration: 
    00:00:08.12
    , start: 
    0.000000
    , bitrate: 
    17298 kb/s
        Stream #0:0
    (eng)
    : Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1920x1080, 16309 kb/s
    , SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9
    , 
    28.70 fps, 
    29.50 tbr, 
    90k tbn, 
    60 tbc
     (default)
        Metadata:
          rotate          : 
    90
          creation_time   : 

          handler_name    : 
    VideoHandle
        Side data:
          
    displaymatrix: rotation of -90.00 degrees
        Stream #0:1
    (eng)
    : Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 192 kb/s
     (default)
        Metadata:
          creation_time   : 
    2020-08-12T17:21:49.000000Z
          handler_name    : 
    SoundHandle
Input #1, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'input2.mp4':
      Metadata:
        major_brand     : 
    isom
        minor_version   : 
    512
        compatible_brands: 
    isomiso2avc1mp41
   encoder         : 
    Lavf57.25.100
      Duration: 
    00:00:05.97
    , start: 
    0.000000
    , bitrate: 
    770 kb/s
        Stream #1:0
    (und)
    : Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 22050 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s
     (default)
        Metadata:
          handler_name    : 
    SoundHandler
        Stream #1:1
    (und)
    : Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 368x480, 608 kb/s
    , 
    27.29 fps, 
120 tbr, 
    12k tbn, 
    60 tbc
     (default)
        Metadata:
          handler_name    : 
    VideoHandler
Input #2, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'input3.mp4':
      Metadata:
        major_brand     : 
    isom
        minor_version   : 
    512
    compatible_brands: 
    isomiso2avc1mp41
        encoder         : 
    Lavf55.19.104
      Duration: 
    00:00:13.05
    , start: 
    0.000000
    , bitrate: 
    2453 kb/s
        Chapter #2:0: 
    start 0.000000, 
    end 13.033000
        Metadata:
          title           : 
        Stream #2:0
    (und)
    : Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s
     (default)
        Metadata:
          handler_name    : 
    SoundHandler
        Stream #2:1
    (und)
: Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 640x480, 2320 kb/s
    , 
    25 fps, 
    25 tbr, 
    1200k tbn, 
    50 tbc
     (default)
        Metadata:
          handler_name    : 
    VideoHandler
        Stream #2:2
    (eng)
    : Data: bin_data (text / 0x74786574), 0 kb/s
        Metadata:
          handler_name    : 
    SubtitleHandler
Input #3, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'transition1.mp4':
      Metadata:
        major_brand     : 
    mp42
        minor_version   : 
    0
        compatible_brands: 
    mp41isom
    creation_time   : 
    2020-08-17T09:31:23.000000Z
      Duration: 
    00:00:03.03
    , start: 
    0.000000
    , bitrate: 
    6263 kb/s
        Stream #3:0
    (und)
    : Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 6307 kb/s
    , 
    30 fps, 
    30 tbr, 
    30k tbn, 
    60 tbc
     (default)
        Metadata:
          creation_time   : 

          handler_name    : 
    VideoHandler
          encoder         : 
    AVC Coding
        Stream #3:1
    (und)
    : Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 79 kb/s
     (default)
        Metadata:
          creation_time   : 
    2020-08-17T09:31:23.000000Z
          handler_name    : 
SoundHandler
Input #4, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'transition2.mp4':
      Metadata:
        major_brand     : 
    mp42
        minor_version   : 0
        compatible_brands: 
    mp41isom
        creation_time   : 
    2020-08-17T09:30:33.000000Z
      Duration: 
    00:00:03.05
    , start: 
    0.000000
    , bitrate: 
    7828 kb/s
        Stream #4:0
    (und)
    : Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 7873 kb/s
    , 
    30 fps, 
30 tbr, 
    30k tbn, 
    60 tbc
     (default)
        Metadata:
          creation_time   : 
    2020-08-17T09:30:33.000000Z
          handler_name    : 
    VideoHandler
          encoder         : 
    AVC Coding
        Stream #4:1
    (und)
    : Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 79 kb/s
     (default)
        Metadata:
          creation_time   : 
    2020-08-17T09:30:33.000000Z
          handler_name    : 
    SoundHandler
Stream mapping:
      Stream #0:0 (h264) -> pad
      Stream #0:1 (aac) -> concat:in0:a0
Stream #1:0 (aac) -> concat:in1:a0
      Stream #1:1 (h264) -> pad
      Stream #2:0 (aac) -> concat:in2:a0
      Stream #2:1 (h264) -> pad
      Stream #3:0 (h264) -> scale
      Stream #4:0 (h264) -> scale
      overlay
     -> Stream #0:0 (libx264)
      concat
     -> Stream #0:1 (aac)
    Press [q] to stop, [?] for help

[graph 0 input from stream 0:0 @ 0x733a19a900] sws_param option is deprecated and ignored
    [graph 0 input from stream 1:1 @ 0x733a19aa80] sws_param option is deprecated and ignored
    [graph 0 input from stream 2:1 @ 0x733a19ab40] sws_param option is deprecated and ignored
    [graph 0 input from stream 3:0 @ 0x733a19ac00] sws_param option is deprecated and ignored
    [graph 0 input from stream 4:0 @ 0x733a19acc0] sws_param option is deprecated and ignored

[mp4 @ 0x733a679400] Frame rate very high for a muxer not efficiently supporting it.
    Please consider specifying a lower framerate, a different muxer or -vsync 2
[libx264 @ 0x733a1b0600] using SAR=1/1
[libx264 @ 0x733a1b0600] MB rate (8160000000) > level limit (16711680)
[libx264 @ 0x733a1b0600] using cpu capabilities: ARMv8 NEON
[libx264 @ 0x733a1b0600] profile Constrained Baseline, level 6.2, 4:2:0, 8-bit
    [libx264 @ 0x733a1b0600] 264 - core 160 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2020 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=0 ref=1 deblock=0:0:0 analyse=0:0 me=dia subme=0 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=0 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=0 8x8dct=0 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=0 threads=12 lookahead_threads=2 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=0 weightp=0 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=0 intra_refresh=0 rc=crf mbtree=0 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=0
Output #0, mp4, to 'output.mp4':
      Metadata:
        major_brand     : 
    mp42
minor_version   : 
    0
        compatible_brands: 
    isommp42
        com.android.version: 
    9
        encoder         : 
    Lavf58.48.100
        Chapter #0:0: 
    start 0.000000, 
    end 13.033000
        Metadata:
          title           : 
        Stream #0:0
    : Video: h264 (libx264) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(progressive), 1080x1920 [SAR 1:1 DAR 9:16], q=-1--1
    , 
    1000k tbn, 
    1000k tbc
(default)
        Metadata:
          encoder         : 
    Lavc58.96.100 libx264
        Side data:
          
    cpb: 
    bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 
    vbv_delay: N/A
        Stream #0:1
    : Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s
     (default)
        Metadata:
          encoder         : 
    Lavc58.96.100 aac
E/Progress: Progress: 3.6918316
D/mobile-ffmpeg: Progress: frame: 1, time: 1002, Pct: 0.036918
frame=    1 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:01.00 bitrate=   0.5kbits/s speed=1.79x    
More than 1000 frames duplicated
```

I even tried command without overlay and audio parts but result was same. I am working on Android app and using below ffmpeg wrapper library:

https://github.com/tanersener/mobile-ffmpeg

Comment: Consider uploading all input files somewhere to be able to reproduce bug you found.

Comment: I have answered my own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got the solution here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63488697/ffmpeg-command-execution-never-stops/63490769?noredirect=1#comment112272999_63490769

I had to add `-vsync 0` to prevent frame duplication.